# How I can detect in Android Kotlin if I swipe over an ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin

I wonder how I can detect when I switch to an ImageView. I don't know how I can do this, any solutions?
Using Android 7 and Kotlin

If u need more information, tell me

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you please explain more, I don't get this phrase **I switch to an ImageView**

Comment: I touch on my Screen than I wanna that my Code can detect if I switch/swipe my Finger to an ImageView as example and open anything or send an Message. Is this enough or I explained again not so good? @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI

Comment: ahh, I see, you want to detect the gesture events (if the user swipe up, down, left or right)?

Comment: Yes but only if I reach the ImageView and than hold up my finger not if I let my finger on screen or swipe little bit behind or before the imageview @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI

Comment: if you provide me any example, I will gladly help you

Comment: I have added an example above, I tap on the screen and swip up and then when I am on the square and move my finger off the screen I am redirected to Activity2 as example @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI